# How do I parameterize an extended Collection

Tags: java, collections, parameterized, extends

I've been trying to extend the ArrayList class without much success. I want to extend it, and be able to parameterize it.

So normally you have something like

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
```

I want

```
MyList<SomeObject> list = new MyList<SomeObject>();
```

Simply extending ArrayList doesn't work.

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList ...
```

The when I try to use it I get the error

> The type MyList is not generic; it
>   cannot be parameterized with arguments
>   <SomeObject>

I've tried variations of

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList<Object>
public class MyList<SubObject> extends ArrayList<Object>
```

with no success, If I use the subobject behind the class name it appears to work, but hides methods in the subobject class for some reason.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to get this working right are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify a type for the `ArrayList`'s type parameter. For generic type parameters, `T` is fairly common. Since the compiler doesn't know what a `T` is, you need to add a type parameter to `MyList` that can have the type passed in. Thus, you get:

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

Additionally, you may want to consider implementing `List` and delegating to an `ArrayList`, rather than inheriting from `ArrayList`. "Favor object composition over class inheritance. [*Design Patterns* pg. 20]"

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyList<T> 
    extends ArrayList<T>
{
}

MyList<SomeObject> list = new MyList<SomeObject>();
```

or

```
public class MyList
    extends ArrayList<SomeObject>
{
}

MyList list = new MyList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't extend ArrayList, extend [AbstractList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) instead:

```
public class MyList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    public int size() {...}
    public T get(int index) {...}
}
```